# Save selected value of a dropdown list in a global variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to save the dropdown list selected value in a glbal variable .. I have lots of country on the dropdown list , whan I choose one of them and press a button :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button2.Enabled = true;
        Button2.Visible = true;
        DropDownList1.Visible = true;

        DropDownList9.Items.Clear();


        if (!Class1.Search_Continent.Equals("-"))
        {
            SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=AK-PC\MSSQLSERVER1;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=True");
            conn1.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Select Country_name FROM Country WHERE Continent_name='" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "'", conn1);
            SqlDataReader dr1;
            dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr1.Read())
            { DropDownList9.Items.Add(dr1["Country_name"].ToString() + "\n"); }

            dr1.Close();
            conn1.Close();
```

}

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Redirect to Country page
        Class1.CountryName = DropDownList9.SelectedValue.ToString();
        Response.Redirect("Country.aspx", true);
    }
```

it doesnt take the selected value ! it always take the first value of the dropdown list !
Please help me !

Answer (score 1):

You are probably re-binding the `DropDownList9` on postback and losing the `SelectedValue`.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostback)
    {
       //bind data
    }
}
```

Comment: Put the code that fills the drop down to the place where it says //bind data

Comment: you should code what you want to happen in the if(!Is.PostBack) as rick has suggested..

Comment: i fill the drop down list from the database ,, and the code is not in page load !

Answer (score 0):

> it always take the first value of the dropdown list

This is very common in web forms if you're populating the data incorrectly.  Where are you populating the drop down list?  I'm going to *guess* that you're doing it in `Page_Load`.  I'm also going to *guess* that you don't have it wrapped in something like `if (!IsPostBack)`.  If you put a debugging breakpoint in `Page_Load` you'll find that it's called in the post-back *before* `Button2_Click` is called.

Keep in mind that HTTP is *stateless*.  This means that the entire server-side page object needs to be constructed on each request to the server.  `Page_Load` is part of that construction, and [it happens before event handlers do](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).  So what's likely happening is:

1. User requests initial page.
2. You populate the drop down list with data.
3. You display the page to the user.
4. User selects an option and clicks a button, making a post-back request.
5. You clobber and re-populate the drop down list, returning it to a default state.
6. You try to get the selected value, which is now gone.

The most common solution to this problem is to use the aforementioned conditional in `Page_Load`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // some initial logic
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // stuff that should only happen when the page first loads
        // for example, populating controls from the database
    }
    // any other logic, etc.
}
```

The values for the controls shouldn't need to be re-populated with each postback because things like viewstate should keep the necessary data available.  (Though if you mess with that at all then you might need to tinker some more.)

Comment: @user1915452: Then where are you populating it?  The description of the problem still suggests that it's being re-populated with each post-back.  Can you expand the code in your question to show more information?

Comment: @user1915452: You can (and should) in an edit to the original question.  Putting code in a comment generally doesn't work very well.

Comment: @user1915452: For one thing, your code contains a SQL injection vulnerability.  You might want to fix that :)  More to the point... So you're populating it in a post-back and then using it in another post-back?  Interesting.  There may be more going on here. One thing you might try it to put a break point in each code-behind function and step through a normal use of the page. Each time you get to a function, check the status of the drop down list and see if it has the selected value or if it's been re-populated. This should at least narrow down the order of execution and help locate the issue.